# How to pass binary image to Awesomium WebControl in VB.Net Applications

Tags: controls, web-controls, awesomium

I'm creating a UI Design for my application in VB.Net with the help of HTML5 and CSS3 and Awesomium WebControl.

In my application I have to fetch binary data from a database and convert it to an Image Object and I have to show the Image in the application. The problem is that I want my UI Design to be full html and css and I don't know how to pass an Image Object in .NET to the Awesomium WebControl in a way that it show the image in html element.

Or in another way:
For Example:
 How to pass my "My.Resources.MyImage" object to the Awesomium WebControl?

```
Dim img As System.Drawing.Image = My.Resources.MyImage
WebControl1.   <----------- How To Pass The Object to the Control?
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awesomium is actually designed exactly for scenarios such as this.

The best way to achieve this in **1.7 RC3** is by using a [`DataSource`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=T_Awesomium_Core_Data_DataSource) and load your resource using the `asset://` protocol. For application resources in particular, we've added a predefined [`ResourceDataSource`](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=T_Awesomium_Core_Data_ResourceDataSource).

Check the WPF *WebControlSample* available with the [SDK](http://awesomium.com/download/), for an example of usage.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but this is not a feature of the Awesomium WebControl.

My Solution: I converted my image to string and then used the usual way of showing string images.

```
Dim myPNGImage As Image = My.Resources.MyImage
Dim strImage As String = Convert.ToBase64String(ImageToByteArray(myPNGImage))

WebControl1.LoadHTML("<img src='data:image/png;base64," & strImage & "' alt=''  />")
```

So while this works, I would like to know a better solution.

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me. vb.net doesnt recognize the imagetobytearray. i even declared it as a byte. nothing.